# open switch controller dependency issue

Tags: installation, mininet

I have installed mininet from the website Click [here](http://mininet.org/download/)!
Later when I tried a example (Map reduce emulation) using mininet I got the output  as "cannot found required executable ovs controller". So i tried installing ovs controller using sudo apt-get install openvswitch-controller but i again got error as unmet dependencies.

Though $ sudo mn --test pingall works fine! But the example I am running gives error.Click [here](https://github.com/mvneves/mremu)!

***Cannot find required ovs controller***
[image]

***Following package has unmet dependencies***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which installation option you've used from the link that you have provided. I found option 3 ("Installation from Packages") to be the simplest.

Mininet requires not only openvswitch-controller, but also some other ovs componenets. Try the following:

```
apt-get install openvswitch-common openvswitch-datapath-dkms openvswitch-controller openvswitch-pki openvswitch-switch
```

Comment: I used what you have mentioned but still I have the same error.        **The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openvswitch-controller : Depends: openvswitch-common (= 2.0.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.3) but 2.3.1-1 is to be installed
                          Depends: openvswitch-pki (= 2.0.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.3) but 2.3.1-1 is to be installed
 openvswitch-switch : Depends: openvswitch-common (= 2.0.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.3) but 2.3.1-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**

Comment: Try apt-get remove all ovs packages and mininet. Then, follow installation instructions of option 3.